# hibernate if data exist save proper foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I made table Employee with foreign key from table Address. When I saving new Employee I want to check if in table Address is already exist that address and if exist dont make new row in Address but find proper and save it in Employee.

I made this like procedure with SQL but is it easier way to do it with hibernate? With this code I always have new rows. I tried to make query to extract but I don't know how to use this address ID to assign to Employee, not to insert new row in address. On picture is table so it is obvious what I want.
[table look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY7A0.png) ,
[link to project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pruwiln6hgwsr88/proj.zip?dl=0)

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
Address address = new Address();
City city = new City();


 /*   Query query = session.createQuery("select  a.address_id  from Address  
a where a.street = :addName").setParameter("addName" , 
JFClasss.insStreet.getText());
List list = query.list();
if(!list.isEmpty()){

    addid = (int) list.get(0);
    address.setAddressId(addid);
   // save = 1;

} */

   address.setStreet(jf.insStreet.getText());
   city.setCityName(jf.insStreet.getText());
   employee.setName(jf.insName.getText());
   employee.setSurname(jf.insSurname.getText());
   employee.setAge(age);
   employee.setAddress(address);
   employee.setCity(city);


 session.saveOrUpdate(city);
 session.save(address);
 session.save(employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I can take whole object and save it again with saveOrUpdate.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
Address address;
City city = new City();


Query query = session.createQuery("select  a.address_id  from Address  a 
where a.street = :addName").setParameter("addName" , 
JFClasss.insStreet.getText());
List list = query.list();
if(!list.isEmpty()){

    addid = (int) list.get(0);
    address = (Address) session.get(Address.class, addid);
   // address.setAddressId(addid);
   // save = 1;

} 
else{
      address = new Address();
      address.setStreet(jf.insStreet.getText());
  }
 .
 .
 .
  session.saveOrUpdate(address);
```